# Javascript height property not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, html, properties, height

https://jsfiddle.net/h2nhb5ah/2/

Does anyone know why my variable `scrollratio` isn't taking on the correct value (ie the ratio of height of `div#left` to `div#right`)?

If the variable `scrollratio` is exchanged for a number then the code works, but the variable itself does not seem to.

Ideally I would also like to figure out a way to use `body.style.height` instead of the `8`.

Comment: simple debugging would tell you why: `console.log(document.getElementById('right').style.height, menu.style.height)`

Comment: That was literally the first thing I did (of course), the console displayed nothing.

Comment: Because there is no style height set for the elements...

Comment: Alright, I understand, style height is somehow different from actual height. Thanks, I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

To get the height of an element, use the `clientHeight` property:

```
var scrollratio = document.getElementById('right').clientHeight / menu.clientHeight;
// => 2.051948051948052
```